# Add pagination to my search engine

Tags: php, sql, pagination, search-engine

**How can I add pagination to a search engine results page?**

I have build a search engine but there are hundreds of thousands of results for every search so I want to add pages to it.

The results of the search engine are outputted in a table.
I have started to learn php and sql recently...

How can I add those pages?

I have tried this so far but with no success:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect(xxxx);
mysqli_select_db($con, 'Data') or die("could not find the database!");
$output = '';

$results_per_page = 1000;

//positioning

if(isset($_GET['search']))
    {
    $starttime = microtime(true);       //TIME 
    $searchkey = $_GET['search'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email LIKE '%$searchkey%'") or die("Could not search") ;
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    // count number of pages for the search
    $number_of_pages = ceil($count/$results_per_page);
    // determine which page number visitor is currently on
    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) 
        {
        $page = 1;
        }
    else 
        {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
    // LIMIT
    $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;




    if ($count == 0) 
        {
        echo "</br>";
        $output = 'There are no search results !' ;

        }
    else 
        {

        echo '<table class="myTable">'; 
        echo "<tr><th>aaa</th><th>bbb</th></tr>"; 
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email LIKE '%$searchkey%' LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page" ") or die("Could not search") ;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
            $email = preg_replace('/(' . $searchkey . ')/i', '<mark>\1</mark>', $row["aaa"]);
            $password = $row['bbb'];
            echo "<tr><td>"; 
            echo $aaa;
            echo "</td><td>";   
            echo $bbb; 
            echo "</td></tr>";
            $output = '</table>';
            }
        //echo "</table>";
        $endtime = microtime(true);
        $duration = $endtime - $starttime;
        echo "</br>";
        if ($count == 1) 
            {
            echo "<div class=resinfo>";
            echo '<div>'."1 result was found for '$searchkey' in $duration seconds.".'</div>'.'</br>';
            echo "</div>";
            } 
        else 
            {
            echo "<div class=resinfo>";
            echo '<div>'."$count results were found for '$searchkey' in $duration seconds.".'</div>'.'</br>';
            echo "</div>";
            }
        }
    echo $output;
    }
//LINKS to other pages
for ($page = 1; $page<=$number_of_pages;$page++){
echo '<a href="search.php?search=' . $searchkey . ' &page=' . $page . ' ">' . $page . '</a>';
}


?>
```

What have I done wrong, what can I improve to make it work?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Your title seems to be asking about pagination, but your actual question is more like "why is this code not working."  What is the real question?

Comment: I want to know how to add pages to my search engine and the code is what I tried to do so far but did not succeed. I want to know if there is a better way of adding pages or if the path I chose is good but with a few mistakes.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: you think you could help me @TimBiegeleisen ?

Comment: Narrow down your question please.

Comment: The question is : How can I add pagination to a search engine results page?

Comment: Look into using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to build a pagination from scratch, instead use a lib like this: https://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components/blob/master/doc/pager/intro.md